# ExtJS ComponentQuery and Dynamic content

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a layout with multiple grids, and they all use RowEditing plugin.  I am trying to use Ext.ComponentQuery.query to get access to the embedded RowEditor buttons on specific grids, but am unable to figure out how to properly traverse things.  I wonder if it has to do with the RowEditor and buttons being added dynamically - though I cannot find anything to confirm that is expected or not.

**Edited to Add jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/ttubbs/eadfpxao/

Once the RowEditing has been activated in each grid (double click a row in each one), running the following in the console produces indicated results...

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("roweditorbuttons") // two results
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("roweditorbuttons > #update") // two results
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#grid1 > roweditorbuttons") // no results
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#grid1 >  #update") // no results

Ext.ComponentQuery.query("roweditorbuttons > button[text=Update]") // two results
```

I need to be able to do something like the following, but the queries don't work:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#grid2 > #update") // give me the update button in #grid2
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#update").up().itemId === "grid1" // determine which grid my button is in
```

The questions are:

- Given a grid (#grid1[1]), how can I get access to the row editor
  buttons?
- Given a button (#update[0]), how can I get access to its
  parent grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should change your `itemId` to `id` in your grids in this example. "itemId" doesnt matter in your example. 
Lets say your grid has `id=grid1`, and your roweditor plugins have `pluginId=roweditor`:

```
var plugin = Ext.getCmp("grid1").getPlugin("roweditor");
// you can get the update button like this
var updateBtn = plugin.editor.floatingButtons.down("button");
// you can get the grid from the plugin as well
var grid = plugin.grid;
```

Comment: Knew I was missing something.  However, still not working for me.  I've updated the  jsfiddle to include ids, though can get component via itemId too.  Don't think that part matters too much.  However, given the component 'Ext.getCmp("myGrid1").getPlugin("roweditor")' returns undefined.  (So does "rowediting")

Comment: What is not working? I tried again and it worked. However, you forgot to give `pluginId` to roweditors. If you wont give it, you can call getPlugin() without arguments. And also, floatingButtons can be achieved only if roweditor is active.

Comment: Right, missed that step!  That works, thanks. `Ext.getCmp("myGrid2").getPlugin('rowEditor2').editor.floatingButtons.down("button")`

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with this selection

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('roweditorbuttons > button[text=Update]')[0]
```

please find the screenshot.[image]

Comment: I need to get to it from a specific grid. This will still give me multiple buttons if multiple row editors are active on the page.